# Who parent if we to use rules in Scarpy?

Tags: scrapy

rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//need_data',
            deny=deny_urls), callback='parse_info'),
       Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/need/', deny=deny_urls), follow=True),
    )

`rules` to extract need URLs for scraping, right?
Can I in callback `def` get URL we move?
For example.
website - needdata.com
`Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/need/', deny=deny_urls), follow=True),` to extract URL like needdata.com/need/1 , right?

```
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        restrict_xpaths='//need_data',
        deny=deny_urls), callback='parse_info'),
```

to extract urls from needdata.com/need/1 , for example it a table with people.
and then `parse_info` to scrape it. Right?
But I want to understand in `parse_info` who a parent?
If needdata.com/need/1 has needdata.com/people/1
I want to add to a file column `parent` and data will be needdata.com/need/1
How to do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to use

```
lx = LinkExtractor(allow=(r'shop-online/',))
```

And then

```
for l in lx.extract_links(response):
    # l.url - it our url
```

And then use

```
meta={'category': category}
```

The better decision I do not find.